# What wire rating do I need for a WS2812b LED strip?

Tags: arduino, wire, ws2812b, gauge

I am looking to make my first Arduino project. I use 140 LEDs of a WS2812B strip. I've got a 5 V, 15 A power supply plugged into a breadboard that goes to my Arduino and my LED strip. I have a roll of 24 awg wire. Is that appropriately gauged for this power?

Comment: Also depends on the topology in which you arrange your strip in space. If both ends are close, you can connect just one power terminal of each end to the PS: the voltage will be the same at each module "no matter" the wire gauge. For all I don't know about those drivers, you could connect the controller anywhere  (if not at one end, you get two strips logically), just don't straddle "the gap" at the PS.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how much wire you use, 24AWG has roughly 25mΩ per foot.  Each WS2812B led at full power uses 60mA with a total 8.4 amps. This means if you used 10ft of 24AWG, it would be a 2.1V drop (8.4V*0.25Ω = 2.1V), which the LED's could tolerate since they can use 3.3V to 5V, but you might see some dimming in the LED's. So if you are using lengths like 10ft, it might be good to double up the conductors of 24AWG wire or use a bigger gauge.